# How can I safely get rid of the odor caused by EasyOff oven cleaner?

Tags: cleaning, oven, odors

I recently cleaned my oven with something called **EasyOff Fume Free**. It worked great at getting the crud off my oven, but now, for the life of me, I can't get rid of the smell.

The "fume free" part of their marketing is a joke. If I turn the oven on, even at its lowest setting (~100 degrees), it starts emitting a nauseating odor that chokes me out and makes my throat sore. I opened up all the windows, opened the doors, started a big room fan, and left the house for an hour. I came back and the smell was still there. It only goes away after I turn the oven off.

I tried washing the inside of the oven with water and a sponge, and that didn't seem to help.

**Is this normal?!?** Has anyone else had a similar experience with this (or similar) oven cleaning products? What was the fix?

Comment: I used the same product a couple of years ago, but the smell dissipated after a couple of hours or so, and didn't even need the oven to run. Are you sure you followed all instructions, and cleaned up all residue?

Comment: I haven't even touched EasyOff in 25 years - every oven I've seen/had has a "clean" cycle that works like a champ.

Comment: Dumb question, to get it out of the way: Have you contacted the manufacturer to get their advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to burn off any residue. This is going to take a very hot temp for several hours. If your oven has a self clean then try using that, otherwise I'd set it to max temp for 2-3hrs and then give it several more hours to cool off before you open it and wipe away any remaining residue.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to get rid of strong odors, I use a tray of vinegar.  It doesn't have to be a lot of vinegar.  Try to maximize the vinegar to air surface (shallow pan).  Leave it in there overnight, and it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try heating it on bake at max and placing a pan of water on the lowest rack. Once boiling, leave to boil for an hour and toward the end turn on fan bake.

It should help to suppress the odor.